# app.php shown as plain text on Symfony 3

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony-3.1

Setting up my app to EC2 instance, I have the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName melomaniacs.com

   ## Vhost docroot
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myProject/web"
   DirectoryIndex  app.php

   ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html/myProject/web

<Directory "/var/www/html/myProject/web">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
        Satisfy Any
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

   ## Logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/melomaniacs_error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/melomaniacs_access.log" combined

   ## Server aliases
   ServerAlias *.melomaniacs.com
   SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

   ## Custom fragment

 </VirtualHost>
```

But when I'm trying to get to app.php (When I access to the IP) I'm getting its content as plain text:

```
loadClassCache(); $kernel = new AppCache($kernel); // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**UPDATE**:
 Just Tried to add into httpd.conf the line:

`LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` 
but it it says:

```
[warn] module php7_module is already loaded, skipping when restarting apache.
```

I have tried many possible configurations but I can't get it, any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install php   and enable its extension for your web server

Comment: then it is probably not enabled for apache, because your apache is not feeding the page trough the php processor

Comment: Where I can enable?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 (if your system supports apt-get),   and restart apache afterwards

Comment: Thanks Sam. i'm using centos 6.5, so sudo yum install  libapache2-mod-php7.0, right?

Comment: just i did it. This lib is not available. Just Add into httpd.conf the line LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so but it it says: [warn] module php7_module is already loaded, skipping when restarting apache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148527/discussion-between-albeis-and-sam-janssens).

Comment: @Albeis :- What was the fix done on this issue to get it working.?